# HDD spin down too fast

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have external HDD connected to Raspberry Pi. I want to set the spindown time to 5 minutes. When I use `sudo hdparm -S 60 /dev/sda` it works fine. Of course, I set up APM before to 127 by `sudo hdparm -B 127 /dev/sda`. I want this configuration to apply after reboot of Raspberry Pi so I added to  /etc/hdaprm.conf the following lines:

`/dev/sda { apm = 127 spindown_time = 60  }`

After reboot, my disk have APM set to 127 but spindown time is not 5 minutes. When I tried to reach my HDD, it will spin down in 2 or 3 sec. I don't konw how to solve this issue. Can anybody help me and explain why this happened?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you set the time via the command?

Comment: Well, if set it via command line, it take longer to get to spindown but it still to short. I set hdparm -S 60 , it should be 60*5 = 5 minutes. It take only aproximatelly 6-8 sec. If I set spindown_time  to 60 in hdaprm.conf, it take only 1 - 2 sec. Do you have any idea where could be problem? Do you need output from `hdparam -I` ?

Comment: No, I don't know much about it.  It's always worked for me, including on Pis, but really that only amounts to a handful of disks.  I have heard it does not work properly with everything, you could try searching online for `hdparm WhateverBrand Model` to see if anyone else has had the same problem.

Comment: I tryed it but I did not find anything about my model (ADATA HD710 1T). I also try to check datasheet, but on their web is just 2 pages of information about colour and other not important information. It was not usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found that tlp service was the cause. I did a "apt purge tlp" and my disks stopped spinning down in seconds.